# How to call a graph within a function definition in networkx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, networkx

Following is my code. I want to call the graph written inside the function as ktgraph. I want to find out how many nodes a bdsize of 6 has but when I type number_of_nodes(ktgraph) it is not callable. How do I do this?

```
def MyBoard(bdSize):
    ktGraph = nx.Graph()
    ktGraph.add_node(bdSize) 
    for row in range(bdSize):
       for col in range(bdSize):
           nodeId = (row*bdSize) + col
           newPositions = MoveTo(row,col,bdSize)
           for e in newPositions:
               nid = e[0]*bdSize+ e[1]
               ktGraph.add_edge(nodeId,nid)
               no = ktGraph.number_of_nodes()
    return nx.draw(ktGraph, with_labels = True)
```

Comment: The line `number_of_nodes(ktgraph)` is not present in the code you showed us.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variable scope issue.
The variable ktGraph has a local scope and can only be accessed from inside the function. You can either print your desired values from inside the function, return the variable and catch it, or just assign the local variable to a global variable outside the function and use it freely.

Example:

```
global_var_outside_func
def MyBoard(bdSize):
    ktGraph = nx.Graph()
    ktGraph.add_node(bdSize) 
    for row in range(bdSize):
       for col in range(bdSize):
           nodeId = (row*bdSize) + col
           newPositions = MoveTo(row,col,bdSize)
           for e in newPositions:
               nid = e[0]*bdSize+ e[1]
               ktGraph.add_edge(nodeId,nid)
               no = ktGraph.number_of_nodes()

    #referencing a global variable using global keyword
    global global_var_outside_func

    #assign the desired variable to it for inspection
    global_var_outside_func = ktGraph

    return nx.draw(ktGraph, with_labels = True)
```